# Which block cipher modes are best used in real life situations?

Tags: block-cipher, symmetric, des

For an exam I'm studying for, I'm wondering what block cipher modes are best to use in certain situations.

We learned about these block cipher modes: ECB, CBC, CFB (+ s-bit), OFB (+ s-bit) and CTR.
From what I understand: some can be parallized, some can't. Some can be turned into a stream cipher (s-bit), some can't. Some have worse error propagation. They each have their (dis)advantages.

My question is, which block cipher methods are preferred in certain situations, for example for video chats, to store passwords, to send data with a micro-controller, ...

Comment: Welcome to Cryptography.Se This is rather a wide question that cannot be answered completely.

Comment: Well, there's a great chance my professor will still ask me this on the exam, and I will need to provide an answer... For example, to store passwords, it's a really bad idea to use ECB because equal blocks get encrypted in the same way. I'm looking for other clues like that.

Comment: For passwords, we don't encrypt we use password hashing algorithms, this is the correct answer.  See [How to securely hash passwords?](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/211/86735). If you insist on encryption then how do you keep the encryption key safely?

Comment: IMO, one of GCM-SIV, GCM, OCB, CTR, or XTS for encryption (not password hashing). OCB is fastest but not as widely supported (it was patented until recently) and not nonce-misuse resistant, GCM-SIV is good for most uses and is nonce-misuse resistant but is 2-pass, GCM is common but not nonce-misuse-resistant, XTS doesn't authenticate and is thus weaker but doesn't expand ciphertext so it's used for full-disk encryption, and CTR is a building-block for authenticated modes and occasionally used where authentication is provided at another level of a protocol. The rest are much less useful.

Comment: @kelalaka Sometimes we do encrypt passwords, it depends on what the password is being used for.  If it's being used for us to authenticate then we don't, if we're storing the password to authenticate to something else then we do encrypt.

Comment: @kelalaka: "*For passwords, we don't encrypt we use password hashing algorithms*" - This is true only in one case, when passwords are needed to authenticate user. But when user stores passwords in password manager, then of course these passwords or normally the whole password database is encrypted, e.g. with AES-256. If one wants to develop a password manager, it is very important what mode to chose.

Comment: Yes, I've only considered the authentication. Did not mention other usages where one needs the password rather than the hash value.

Comment: ECB is a bad choice for anything. Unless you can guarantee, the same message is never sent twice with the same key. This is a restriction on the messages - and it's better to avoid that.

Answer (score 1):

In real-life situations, except for compatibility with existing systems, it seldom should be directly used any of the encryption modes listed in the question, because they at best provide secure encryption (caveat: ECB does not), which does *not* cover the needs of most real-life situations.

In real applications, if one needs encryption, one also typically needs to prevent undetected alteration of the message (e.g. removing part of it, altering a segment). Thus it's needed a mode that provides encryption *and* authentication¹, such as [GCM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galois/Counter_Mode) combined with the block cipher [AES](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard). It's fast enough for "video chats" with a modern CPU and simple enough to "send data with a micro-controller".

Such [authenticated encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Authenticated_encryption) mode will often internally use one of the question's mode for the encryption that it provides, e.g. GCM uses CTR. ECB/CBC/CFB/OFB tends to be phased out for CTR, because CTR is simple, fast, easily parallelizable, and allows direct read/modify/write access to large files without re-encrypting what follows. It's only drawbacks are

- Malleability², but that's entirely solved by authenticated encryption.
- Sensitivity to reuse of [Initialization Vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initialization_vector)/[nonce](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_nonce). This can be mitigated by good procedures to generate IV, or nonce-misuse-resistant authenticated encryption modes like [GCM-SIV](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8452).

To "store passwords", we often don't want to use encryption, which implies the possibility of decryption, when we often can live with a system that never requires to decrypt passwords and thus is less vulnerable to data leaks (there are some exceptions like password managers). For passwords, the first choice is secure hardware designed for passwords storage. The second choice is to store on disk the result of a deliberately slow and salted hash function of the password, like [Argon2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argon2). The last choice is authenticated encryption of the password. Notice authentication matters: with encryption alone, it's to fear that someone with read/write access to the encrypted passwords can reset a user's password to a known one, without the key, if they know the password of another user.

---

¹ In the sense that deciphered plaintext exactly matches plaintext that was encrypted with the encryption key, which make it authentic.

² In the sense of allowing changing the meaning of deciphered plaintext for known plaintext, e.g. change `pay $1000` to `pay $9800`. CBC or CFB mode make such attack more difficult, but do not provide full authenticated encryption.